# Java: How to get only subdirectories name present at certain level?

Tags: java, directory-structure

Here is my folder structure:

```
parent/
  child1/
    child1.1/
    child1.2/
  child2/
    child 2.1/
    child 2.2/
  child3/
    child 3.1/
    child 3.2/
```

How can I extract only the names of the third-level folders? (I haven't been able to find this online)

Output should be:

```
child1.1 ,child1.2 
child2.1 ,child2.2
child3.1 ,child3.2
```

I referenced [Java: how to get all subdirs recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2581158) to find subdirectories.

Comment: The code you link to is a bit old stuff, today you may use the `Path` and `Files` and related classes in `java.nio.files`. In any case, without thinking very deeply about it, isn’t it just a matter of taking the recursion out of that other code?

Comment: FYI I reformatted your question to make the directory structure clearer. Apologies if I misunderstood what you were describing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make `level` parametric I suggest code:

```
static public List<File> getDirs(File parent, int level){
    List<File> dirs = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = parent.listFiles();
    if (files == null) return dirs; // empty dir
    for (File f : files){
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
             if (level == 0) dirs.add(f);
             else if (level > 0) dirs.addAll(getDirs(f,level-1));
        }
    }
    return dirs;
}
```

And call it:

```
List<File> l = getDirs(new File("/some/path"), 3);
```

Edit: I added verification in case of empty directory

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be recursive, you could use something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    List<File> results = new ArrayList<File>();
    getSubdirs(file, results, 0, 2);
    for (File f : results) {
        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}

public static List<File> getSubdirs(File file, List<File> results, int level, int targetlevel) {
    List<File> subdirs = Arrays.asList(file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.isDirectory();
        }
    }));
    subdirs = new ArrayList<File>(subdirs);
    if (level == targetlevel) results.addAll(subdirs);

    List<File> deepSubdirs = new ArrayList<File>();
    for(File subdir : subdirs) {
        deepSubdirs.addAll(getSubdirs(subdir, results, level + 1, targetlevel)); 
    }
    subdirs.addAll(deepSubdirs);
    return subdirs;
}
```

As you can see, I adapted the original method you referred too.

In this case, we create an empty list `results` and we start with level `0`. Each time the recursive method is called, we add `1` to the level. We also pass a target level (in this case `2`). We add all the results for which the `level` equals the `targetlevel`.

Note that this is much slower than the non-recursive methods shared by the other people (because you loop over *every* subdirectory), but it is more generic.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ole V.V. said. your task is actually simpler than the recursive walk the linked question discusses. You simply need to list the contents of each directory under `parent`, which might look something like this:

```
Path parent = Paths.get("parent");
try (DirectoryStream<Path> childStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(parent)) {
  for (Path child : childStream) {
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> subChildStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(child)) {
      for (Path subChild : subChildStream) {
        // or just print subChild to display the full path
        System.out.println(subChild.getFildName());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could also try [`Files.walkFileTree`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) if you don't want to deal with try-with-resources blocks; setting the max-depth to 2 (since you're starting from `parent`) you can override `preVisitDirectory()` and only print paths two-deeper than `parent`.

**Edit:** The accepted answer uses the legacy `java.io.File` API. Java 7+ code should prefer the [`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) APIs, which my example uses.

Comment: Just to get this straight: Would you mind adding import statements. So that its clear which classes you are using. And which Java version you do?

Comment: @Matthias this is using the [`java.nio.files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) API which Ole V.V. mentioned in their comment. It was introduced in Java 7. I would strongly discourage using `java.io.File` in new code as it has a number of shortcomings which `java.nio.files` addressed.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will do the trick:

```
public List<File> getThirdLayer(File root) {
        List<File> thirdLayerFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
        for (File f : root.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                for (File f2 : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (f2.isDirectory()) {
                        thirdLayerFiles.add(f2);
                    }
                }
            }
            return thirdLayerFiles;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It will return a List of the thirdLayer of your structur!

Comment: Just a note: You should pick up the terminology from the question (parent, child). Also I think that your nested for block is not what you had in mind.

Comment: As Ole V.V. said its not necessary to make it recursively. Also I just thought root is quite the same as parent in this case. But thanks for your note ;D

Answer (score 1):

Here’s an unpolished go.

```
    Path parent = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("parent");
    Files.list(parent).forEach(child -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(Files.list(child).map(Path::getFileName).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO
        }
    });
```

It would print someting like

```
[child1.1, child1.2]
[child2.1, child2.2]
[child3.1, child3.2]
```

I hope you can tailor it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "walkFileTree"-Method in the Files-class.

Here a short example:

```
    Path startingDir = new File("parent").toPath();
    Integer depth = 2;
    EnumSet<FileVisitOption> opts = EnumSet.noneOf(FileVisitOption.class);
    FileVisitor<Path> finder = new FileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            if (attrs.isDirectory()
                    && dir.getNameCount() - startingDir.getNameCount() == depth) {
                System.out.println(dir.toString());
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            //ignore error in subtree
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

    };
    Files.walkFileTree(startingDir, opts, depth + 1, finder);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried my own solution based on comment by Ole V.V

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String path = "D:/PT/Projects/current/1/bwb/2.1";
    File file = new File(path);
    List<File> level1folders = getDir(file); //level 1 folders
    level1folders = new ArrayList<File>(level1folders);
    List<File> level2folders = getSubdirs(level1folders); //level 2 folders
    List<File> level3folders = getSubdirs(level2folders);    ////level 3 folders

    //print
    for (File file2 : level3folders) {
        System.out.println(file2.getName());
    }

}

private static List<File> getDir(File file) {
    List<File> subdirs = Arrays.asList(file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.isDirectory();
        }
    }));
    return subdirs;
}
static List<File> getSubdirs(List<File> subdirs) {
    List<File> deepSubdirs = new ArrayList<File>();
    for(File subdir : subdirs) {
        deepSubdirs.addAll(getDir(subdir)); 
    }
    //subdirs.addAll(deepSubdirs);
    return deepSubdirs;
}
```

But krzydyn is good one! dimo414 is new to me. Thanks